# Como poderia criar a função array_column em versões anteriores ao PHP 5.5

Tags: php, array

De acordo com o Manual do PHP, a função [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-column.php) está disponível a partir do PHP 5.5

Ela retorna o valor de uma "coluna" de um array multidimensional em um único array.

Exemplo:

```
$records = array(
    array(
        'id' => 2135,
        'first_name' => 'John',
        'last_name' => 'Doe',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 3245,
        'first_name' => 'Sally',
        'last_name' => 'Smith',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 5342,
        'first_name' => 'Jane',
        'last_name' => 'Jones',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 5623,
        'first_name' => 'Peter',
        'last_name' => 'Doe',
    )
);

$first_names = array_column($records, 'first_name');

print_r($first_names);
```

Resultado:

```
Array
(
    [0] => John
    [1] => Sally
    [2] => Jane
    [3] => Peter
)
```

Porém a mesma não está presente nas versões anteriores ao PHP 5.5 e essa é uma função muito boa para simplificar uma estrutura de um array quando necessário.

Como poderia desenvolver uma função que fizesse a mesma coisa em versões anteriores do PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É possível implementar o método `array_column` usando a função `array_map`:

```
function array_column(array $array, $column) 
    return array_map(function($row) use($column) {
        return $row[$column];
    }, $array);
}
```

A função `array_map` é suportada desde o PHP 4; porém as *closures* (funções anônimas), como bem notado pelo Wallace Maxters, são suportadas apenas a partir do PHP 5.3. Então esse código funciona nas versões do PHP >= 5.3 e < 5.5.

Por isso, para driblar essa limitação das versões anterioes ao PHP 5.3 quanto ao suporte a  funções anônimas, podemos também utilizar o `foreach` para obter essa funcionalidade:

```
function array_column(array $array, $column)
{
    $new = array();

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {

        $new[] = $value[$column];
    }

    return $new;
}
```

Comment: +1 Curti a função. Ficou bem simples. No caso, a única coisa aí que não é suportando antes das versões 5.3 são as `Closure`s

Comment: Bem notado. Alterei a resposta.

Comment: Se me permite, adicionei um "bônus adicional"  à sua resposta

Comment: Claro. No `foreach` vale a pena verificar se a chave existe, mas isso é tópico para outra pergunta. :)